# Verify an object belongs to a user in MVC/SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authorization

I am trying to optimize the performance of my application. I need to make sure the user is able to retrieve items that ONLY belongs to the logged in user.

Let's say I am getting retrieving an object from database. Which code is more efficient?

```
var _User = db.users.FirstOrDefault(U => U.username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
if (_User == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
var _Articles = db.articles.Where(A => A.user_id == _User.id);
return View(_Articles.ToList());
```

or

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var _Articles = db.articles.Include("user").Where(A => A.user.username == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    return View(_Articles.ToList());
}
return HttpNotFound();
```

I believe the second one is more efficient since we are only making one DB call.

The main purpose of this question is to ask am I doing this the right way? or Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

I also made sure these controller has the [Authorize] attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is more efficent, but you have to consider that on the modern machines the overhead introduced by the first solution is absolutely not measurable!